# comparing two files and outputting common elements

Tags: r

I have 2 files of 3 columns and hundreds of rows. I want to compare and list the common elements of first two columns of the two files. Then the list which i will get after comparing i have to add the third column of second file to that list. Third column will contain the values which were in the second file corresponding to numbers of remaining two columns which i have got as common to both the files.
For example, consider two files of 6 rows and 3 columns
First file -

```
1 2   3
2 3   4
4 6   7
3 8   9
11 10 5
19 6  14
```

second file -

```
1 4   1
2 1   4
4 6   10
3 7   2
11 10 3
19 6  5
```

As i said i have to compare the first two columns and then add the third column of second file to that list. Therefore, output must be:

```
  4  6  10
  11 10 3
  19  6 5
```

I have the following code, however its showing an error object not found also i am not able to add the third column. Please help :)
df2 = reading first file, df3 = reading second file. Code is in R language.

```
s1 = 1
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
 for(j in 1:nrow(df3)){
     if(df2[i,1] == df3[j,1]){
        if(df2[i,2] == df3[j,2]){
             common.rows1[s1,1] <- df2[i,1]
             common.rows1[s1,2] <- df2[i,2]
             s1 = s1 + 1
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%in%` operator twice to subset your second data.frame (I call it `df2`):

```
df2[df2$V1 %in% df1$V1 & df2$V2 %in% df1$V2,]

#  V1 V2 V3
#3  4  6 10
#5 11 10  3
#6 19  6  5
```

`V1` and `V2` in my example are the column names of `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is the perfect use-case for [merge](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html), e.g.

```
merge(d1[c('V1','V2')],d2)
```

results in:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1 11 10  3
2 19  6  5
3  4  6 10
```

In which 'V1' and 'V2' are the column names of interest.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` proposal

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
setkey(df1, V1, V2)
setkey(df2, V1, V2)

df2[df1[, -3, with = F], nomatch = 0]

##    V1 V2 V3
## 1:  4  6 10
## 2: 11 10  3
## 3: 19  6  5
```

Answer (score 0):

If your two tables are `d1` and `d2`,

```
d1<-data.frame(
    V1 = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 11, 19),
    V2 = c(2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 6), 
    V3 = c(3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 14)
)

d2<-data.frame(
    V1 = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 11, 19), 
    V2 = c(4, 1, 6, 7, 10, 6),
    V3 = c(1, 4, 10, 2, 3, 5)
)
```

then you can subset `d2` (in order to keep the third column) with

```
d2[interaction(d2$V1, d2$V2) %in% interaction(d1$V1, d1$V2),]
```

The `interaction()` treats the first two columns as a combined key.